# bootstrap components only partially working with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple website following the One Month Rails tutorial online, and since bootstrap is constantly updating I've decided to mess around with it by myself.

I have the following file home.html.erb and tried to apply the jumbotron effect from bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome to One Month Rails</h1>
    <p>
        You've found the home page!! <%= link_to "Google", "http://www.google.com"%> 
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up Now!", "#" %>
    </p>
</div>
```

The page, however, does not show the jumbotron effect. What am I doing wrong? I know that bootstrap should be working because I've added some styling effects using bootstrap classes like **nav** and **btn**

Edit: I've read from a few other questions and apparantly the jumbotron class is bugged with the rails gem. I will try to manually incoporate bootstrap and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding something else to this particular page and style it using bootstrap (like a simple button)?  That way you can ensure bootstrap is working on this specific page.

I don't see any problem with the code you pasted.

EDIT:

Try this sample code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Welcome to landing page!</h1>
      <p>This is an example for jumbotron.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a>     
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's alright ! I tried adding a large button using the bootstrap class: btn btn-success btn-large to my link and it works perfectly fine. With that I still can't figure out why jumbotron isn't working. I know jumbo use to be called "hero-unit" so I tried that, but as expected it doesn't work

Comment: Alright, try wrapping the jumbotron div in a div with a class of "container"   <div class="container"> @user3277633 see my edit above

Comment: still doesn't work, I think it has to do with the bootstrap gem itself. I'll try to manually incorporate bootstrap to my app. thanks for the help though!

Comment: ah - no problem!  yeah, i don't really use the gem, just link to the cdn, especially if it's not a production type of deal.  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> .  I'd be curious if that solves your problem.  :)